# PHP PostgreSQL PDO can't bind parameter with LIKE

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, bindparam

Using PHP PDO to attempt a simple search for term in database.  The error return implies that `PDO` can't determine the param type.  I'm explicitly specifying it as `STR` when binding it and also casting it to varchar in the query string. The query works fine in MySQL without the CAST.

```
// Get course retry limit from database
$query = $this->db_connection->prepare("
SELECT column FROM datbase.table
WHERE
column LIKE CAST(CONCAT('%', :search_term, '%') as varchar)
GROUP BY column"
);
$query->bindValue(':search_term', $search_term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :search_term
```

If I explicitly escape the string in the query with single quotes as I would do in a direct query call, I get another error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42P18]: Indeterminate datatype: 7 ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

Answer (score 1):

I  solved this by moving the CAST inside directly to the parameter.  Not sure why it's needed since the PHP variable is a string which has been encoded to uppercase.

Here is the correct query:

```
$query = $this->db_connection->prepare("
SELECT column FROM datbase.table
WHERE
column LIKE CONCAT('%', CAST(:search_term as VARCHAR), ' %')
GROUP BY column"
);
$query->bindValue(':search_term', $search_term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```